# Why does a Kotlin function on JVM generate a bridge method?

Tags: kotlin

From https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/15716a7a3c5e6df4b7520fd07ece62ac5db6debf/spec-docs/function-types.md says:

> Each lambda is compiled to an anonymous class which inherits from `FunctionImpl` and implements the corresponding `invoke`:
>
> ```
> { (s: String): Int -> s.length }
>
> // is translated to
>
> object : FunctionImpl(), Function1<String, Int> {
>     override fun getArity(): Int = 1
>
>     /* bridge */ fun invoke(p1: Any?): Any? = ...
>     override fun invoke(p1: String): Int = p1.length
> }
> ```

But there's no explanation why `fun invoke(p1: Any?): Any?` gets to be generated. Its JVM signature would be `Object invoke(Object p1)`. If the language was dynamically typed like Clojure or Groovy, that would totally make sense. But Kotlin is not. I can't really guess the reason. Is there any rationale behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to figure that out by myself after some googling.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

This seems to be rather a Java concern than a Kotlin one. In short:

After [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html),

```
public class <T> Parent<T> {
  public void f(T x) { System.out.println("parent"); }
}
public class Child extends Parent<Integer> {
  public void f(Integer x) { System.out.println("child"); }
}
```

becomes

```
public class Parent {
  public void f(Object x) { ... }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
  public void f(Integer x) { ... }
}
```

which makes `Child.f` not override `Parent.f`. So what Java compiler does is generating a **bridge method**.

```
public class Child extends Parent {
  public void f(Object x) { f((Integer) x); } // bridge method
  public void f(Integer x) { ... }
}
```

Same happens with Kotlin's `Function` objects which have generic type parameters.